# Complex mysql query with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I need your help to solve a hard mysql query.

I've got a table with entries like that :

```
id_table|id_attribut|id_product|value
 1      |         12|        23| #35#
 2      |         15|        23| #12#
 3      |         21|        23| test

 1      |         12|        24| #35#
 2      |         15|        24| #13#
 3      |         21|        24| test
```

And i would like to select id_product where (id_attribut='12' AND value LIKE '%#35#%') AND (id_attribut='15' AND value LIKE '%#12#%').
So i wrote :

```
SELECT * FROM attribut 
WHERE (id_attribut='12' AND value LIKE '%#35#%') 
AND (id_attribut='15' AND value LIKE '%#12#%') 
GROUP BY id_product
```

-> but it's not working :(

I also try inner join on the same table, but it's very very slow to get results.

Any suggestions ?

Thks !

Comment: `...AND value LIKE '%#35#%') OR (id_attribut='15' AND...`

Comment: Also, your `GROUP BY` doesn't really make sense here.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You want to match conditions on different rows.  Your `where` clause is going to fail because the conditions are inconsistent -- they cannot both be true on a single row.  Instead you need to use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT id_product
FROM attribut 
GROUP BY id_product
HAVING SUM(id_attribut='12' AND value LIKE '%#35#%') > 0 AND
       SUM(id_attribut='15' AND value LIKE '%#12#%') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

A select statement returns rows matching the condition you set. In this case your condition reads:
"Return to me rows that have `id_attribut='12' AND value LIKE '%#35#%'` while AT THE SAME TIME ( your middle `AND`) they have `id_attribut='15' AND value LIKE '%#12#%'`". Such rows don't exist since they can only have one value both for the **id_attribut** and the **value** fields.

I suggest to change the middle **AND** to an **OR** and see if that works better for you:

```
SELECT * FROM attribut WHERE (id_attribut='12' AND value LIKE '%#35#%')
OR (id_attribut='15' AND value LIKE '%#12#%') GROUP BY id_product;
```

Comment: I stand corrected. After reading [Gordon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27611430/3438220) I realized that I had misunderstood the Vincent's question. That is if he really wants to use an aggregate function like SUM.

If not, and you just wanted to get back rows that have satisfy either (but not both) of the two conditions in parentheses, then my reply works.